# Is it possible to find who posted comment on my blogspot anonymously?

Tags: web-application, anonymity, user-tracking

**Problem Behind question** :

I own an blogspot site and people used to come and comment on my posts. In recent days I can see a spammer who comments anonymously on my every blog-posts. The comments were posted under the name of anonymous. Is it possible to track the IP or some stuff related to spammer whom makes comments anonymously?

**Question** :

How to detect who commented on my blogpost anonymously?

Comment: In many cases it is possible to find who posted a comment, but it is rarely worth the effort.

Comment: check the link they post, and see if it has a user or referrer ID. check with that site to see if they have any rules against spamming, also, you could either deny anonymous posting, or require approval before the comment becomes visible

Comment: may i know the reason for downvotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way through what you have on Blogger if you have been allowing anonymous comments.

It would be possible for Google to track the IP; but even if they were inclined to react to an abuse report, they would not pass on that information to you.

---

There are indirect ways you could narrow things down if circumstances are right and if you want to spend a lot of time doing a lot of work for uncertain results. Let's call your anonymous comments, T (for Troll). If you can find other things around the net that T has posted (using the same phrases, style, etc) then you may be able to work from those. For example, if T is posting under some pseudonym on a forum that uses Gravatar (even if T doesn't), then you may be able to get an MD5 hash of the email address T used to sign up for that forum.  This sort of de-anonymizing is [described here](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/07/got-an-account-on-a-site-like-github-hackers-may-know-your-e-mail-address/).

Or maybe T boasts about trolling you in some other place. Or something like that.

But these sorts of methods involve a lot of uncertainty. And if T is even half way experienced at this kind of thing, then then the IP is going to be through some proxy anyway, and any email address you find will be a throw away email.

---

It may be presumptuous of me to advise when I don't know the situation, but my inclination is to suggest that you just let it go. Don't let T's actions control your mind. Don't try to seek revenge. Just disable anonymous comments and let things go.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous commenting leads your blog open to spammers. Disable it immediately.
After enabling `who can comment` to `Registered users` you can track everyone who posts.

click on Settings from the drop-down menu on your Dashboard, then go to the area for posts and comments.

Drop-down menu, settings is the last option
Comments section under Settings
There, you'll see all the settings to manage your comments.

[image: Settings]

Comment: This is the way to block anonymous posts ,but i wish to track whom commented on my posts,this might be an alternative solution

Comment: Try This    http://belajarcak.blogspot.in/2011/08/cara-melacak-lokasi-komentar-anonymous.html

Comment: I'm posting it as another answer since this one is also advisable.

Answer (score 1):

Try  installing [web tracker script](http://belajarcak.blogspot.in/2011/08/cara-melacak-lokasi-komentar-anonymous.html). This script will record information about an IP address, referrer sites, mobile operators, and some other useful information to track the location coordinates (latitude and longitude) of visitors.

Any site tracker web site recommended is StatsCounter guide, sign up and install the script on the blog web tracker can be found here.Keep in mind for the user a free restricted maximum of 500 records only the most recent data is displayed, in order not to lose the old data should store data records into excel format.
Specifically discussed in this post about how to utilize the results of tracing the data to obtain more detailed information.

1. Log in to your account StatsCounter web tracker
   Choose one of the blogs available on the project list, in this instance Computers SEO (adjust with the project that you created)
2. The vertical menu pilih Recent Pageload Activity

Sometimes blog owners who use the blogspot is rather difficult to detect the location of visitors who leave a comment as anonymous. Some bloggers disable this feature in the comment form Anonymous blogger to avoid comments that are blasphemous anonymoys without regard to the content / theme of the posting. But there is another way to find out the location of the anonymous comment makers, that is by installing web tracker script. This script will record information about an IP address, referrer sites, mobile operators, and some other useful information to track the location coordinates (latitude and longitude) of visitors.

Any site tracker web site recommended is StatsCounter guide, sign up and install the script on the blog web tracker can be found here.

Keep in mind for the user a free restricted maximum of 500 records only the most recent data is displayed, in order not to lose the old data should store data records into excel format.

Specifically discussed in this post about how to utilize the results of tracing the data to obtain more detailed information.

1. Log in to your account StatsCounter web tracker

Choose one of the blogs available on the project list, in this instance Computers SEO (adjust with the project that you created)

Likewise, the map will make it easier to track spatially

Comment: Please note that tracking a user without her consent (especially while letting her belief she is anonymous) might lead to juristic problems. Maybe not in USA, but in Europe that might be the case. I'm pretty sure it's illegal in Germany.